# How to get the rest of the rows after taking some rows randomly from a dataframe in R

Tags: r, random, dplyr, random-seed

I have 2 dataframe `df_1` and `df_2`. Now I have to select some rows randomly from `df_1` and then I will merge the `rest of the rows (which not selected randomly) from df_1` with `df_2`.

I am using this code

```
set.seed(9999)
df_1 <- # the whole dataset
test_dataset1 <- sample_n(df_1, 10)
train_part_1 <- df_1[which(!df_1 %in% test_dataset1)] # Not working
train_1 <- rbind(df_2, train_part_1)
```

But, when I am trying to extract the rows not selected randomly. My code is not working. I am getting the same data as the `df_1` means `20 rows (same dataset)`

Edited: Actually, I have to make `3 test` and `3 train` datasets. So, how can I use the `seed` function to get the same dataset for reproduce purposes?

Reproducible data (only df_1):

```
structure(list(nodeA = structure(c(4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 
                                   9L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 8L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 7L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("ID00309", 
                                                                                                   "ID00361", "ID00541", "ID00570", "ID00615", "ID00696", "ID00762", 
                                                                                                   "ID01200", "ID05109"), class = "factor"), nodeB = structure(c(8L, 
                                                                                                                                                                 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 9L, 8L, 8L, 6L, 9L, 7L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 9L, 6L, 
                                                                                                                                                                 7L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("ID00361", "ID00541", "ID00570", "ID00615", 
                                                                                                                                                                                         "ID00696", "ID01200", "ID05109", "ID11641", "ID11691"), class = "factor"), 
               scr = structure(20:1, .Label = c("1.85284606048794", "1.90444166064472", 
                                                "1.90762235378507", "1.94364188077133", "1.95883206119256", 
                                                "2.08440437841349", "2.26408172709962", "2.3223132020942", 
                                                "2.46120775935034", "2.49647215035727", "2.50432367561777", 
                                                "2.57541320006514", "2.65099330092281", "2.75209155741549", 
                                                "2.93717640337986", "2.99596628688011", "3.21209741517806", 
                                                "3.21997803385465", "3.48788394772132", "3.81389707587156"
               ), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                          -20L))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get your sample using random row numbers and the use `-` to get the inverse:

```r
df_1 <- structure(list(nodeA = structure(c(4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 9L, 3L, 4L, 
                                         2L, 8L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 7L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 1L), 
                                       .Label = c("ID00309", "ID00361", "ID00541", 
                                                  "ID00570", "ID00615", "ID00696", 
                                                  "ID00762", "ID01200", "ID05109"), 
                                       class = "factor"), 
                     nodeB = structure(c(8L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 9L, 8L, 8L, 6L, 
                                         9L, 7L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 9L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 5L), 
                                       .Label = c("ID00361", "ID00541", "ID00570", 
                                                  "ID00615", "ID00696", "ID01200", 
                                                  "ID05109", "ID11641", "ID11691"), 
                                       class = "factor"), 
                     scr = structure(20:1, .Label = c("1.85284606048794", "1.90444166064472", 
                                                      "1.90762235378507", "1.94364188077133", 
                                                      "1.95883206119256", "2.08440437841349", 
                                                      "2.26408172709962", "2.3223132020942", 
                                                      "2.46120775935034", "2.49647215035727", 
                                                      "2.50432367561777", "2.57541320006514", 
                                                      "2.65099330092281", "2.75209155741549", 
                                                      "2.93717640337986", "2.99596628688011", 
                                                      "3.21209741517806", "3.21997803385465", 
                                                      "3.48788394772132", "3.81389707587156"
                     ), class = "factor")), 
                class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -20L))

set.seed(9999)
Selected <- sample.int(nrow(df_1), 10)
# index selected the row; use [col,row] pattern to select rows
test_dataset1 <- df_1[ Selected, ] 
# use -index to remove rows
train_part_1  <- df_1[-Selected, ] 

test_dataset1
#>      nodeA   nodeB              scr
#> 6  ID00570 ID05109 2.93717640337986
#> 9  ID00541 ID11641 2.57541320006514
#> 19 ID00361 ID00696 1.90444166064472
#> 3  ID00309 ID00570 3.21997803385465
#> 10 ID00570 ID01200 2.50432367561777
#> 2  ID00361 ID00570 3.48788394772132
#> 20 ID00309 ID00696 1.85284606048794
#> 8  ID05109 ID11641 2.65099330092281
#> 12 ID01200 ID05109 2.46120775935034
#> 18 ID00696 ID05109 1.90762235378507
train_part_1
#>      nodeA   nodeB              scr
#> 1  ID00570 ID11641 3.81389707587156
#> 4  ID00309 ID00361 3.21209741517806
#> 5  ID00309 ID00541 2.99596628688011
#> 7  ID00309 ID11691 2.75209155741549
#> 11 ID00361 ID11691 2.49647215035727
#> 13 ID00361 ID00615  2.3223132020942
#> 14 ID00309 ID00615 2.26408172709962
#> 15 ID00615 ID01200 2.08440437841349
#> 16 ID00762 ID11691 1.95883206119256
#> 17 ID00541 ID01200 1.94364188077133
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much. Your code is solving my problem like `selected and -selected` but I am getting different values for `selected` (when I am running multiples times). How can I reproduce the same dataset?

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand what it is you need. Setting the seed should give you the same vector again and again. And - of course - you could also just make sure that `Selected` is not overwritten every time you run it. But since these answers are too simple, it cannot be what you need.

Comment: Thank you. Such as, when I am running this `Selected <- sample.int(nrow(df_1), 10)` I am getting ` 6  9 19  3 10  2 20  8 12 18` and at the time of `Selected_2 <- sample.int(nrow(df_1), 10)` I am getting `18  3  4 10  6 14 19 11 20  8`. That's mean, if I want the same output for `Selected and Selected_2`, then I have to run the program from the very beginning and not overwrite the `Selected`. Right?

Comment: That's where `set.seed()` comes in. Same seed, same random numbers.